# How do I fix the iOS 11 update not appearing on an iPad Air 2?

Tags: ios, ipad, software-update

How do I fix the iOS 11 update not appearing on an iPad? Oddly, the [Software Update](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204204) menu item in the Settings app is showing a red “1” badge, indicating that an update is available. But when opening the item, there’s only a message that the iPad is running iOS 10.3.3 and is up to date. This seems like a bug? I already tried restarting the iPad, but this hasn’t resolved the problem. The iPad is a family member’s iPad Air 2, and there’s more than enough free space to download the update (> 30gb). Is there anything else I can try or is my only recourse to bring a laptop and use iTunes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don’t know what causes this issue. Based on my own experience, all I can suggest others try is to restart the device more than once. In my case, the update didn’t show up until after restarting the iPad twice.

Answer (score 5):

Try restarting it one more time using a force restart. After that it should appear in Settings.